# Recursive type definitions does not seem to work handle generics?

Tags: typescript, generics, recursion, types, partial

I think this is a bug in Typescript and I filed it as an issue [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17799). I don't expect it to be fixed (at least not soon, so I want to ask you guys, does anyone happen to have an idea for a better solution/work-around than create_1?

**Code**

```
type RecursivePartial<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]?: RecursivePartial<T[P]>;
};

type State<T> = { value: T };

function create_1<T>(){

    let _x: RecursivePartial<State<T>>;
    let _y: State<RecursivePartial<T>>;

    _x = _y;
}

function create_2<T>(){
 /*

 */

    let x: RecursivePartial<State<T>>;
    let y: State<T>;

    /*
        Type 'State<T>' is not assignable to type RecursivePartial<State<T>>'.
            Types of property 'value' are incompatible.
                Type 'T' is not assignable to type RecursivePartial<T>[P]>'.
                    Type 'T[string]' is not assignable to type 'RecursivePartial<T[P]>'.
    */

    x = y; 
}
```

**Expected behavior:**
I had expected the second example to be valid typescript, i.e. State should be assignable to RecursivePartial>. This should be the case as any State would be a partial of it self given T is the same type.

**Actual behavior:**
I get a type error (see above), it seems that the recursive type definition breaks when it encounters a generic?

**TS Playground link**
The code and type error can be confirmed here; [ts-playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20RecursivePartial%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5BP%20in%20keyof%20T%5D%3F%3A%20RecursivePartial%3CT%5BP%5D%3E%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20State%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%7B%20value%3A%20T%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20create_1%3CT%3E()%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20_x%3A%20RecursivePartial%3CState%3CT%3E%3E%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20_y%3A%20State%3CRecursivePartial%3CT%3E%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20_x%20%3D%20_y%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20create_2%3CT%3E()%7B%0D%0A%20%2F*%0D%0A%0D%0A%20*%2F%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20x%3A%20RecursivePartial%3CState%3CT%3E%3E%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20y%3A%20State%3CT%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F*%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Type%20'State%3CT%3E'%20is%20not%20assignable%20to%20type%20RecursivePartial%3CState%3CT%3E%3E'.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Types%20of%20property%20'value'%20are%20incompatible.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Type%20'T'%20is%20not%20assignable%20to%20type%20RecursivePartial%3CT%3E%5BP%5D%3E'.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Type%20'T%5Bstring%5D'%20is%20not%20assignable%20to%20type%20'RecursivePartial%3CT%5BP%5D%3E'.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20*%2F%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20x%20%3D%20y%3B%20%0D%0A%7D#src=type%20RecursivePartial%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5BP%20in%20keyof%20T%5D%3F%3A%20RecursivePartial%3CT%5BP%5D%3E%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20State%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%7B%20value%3A%20T%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20create_1%3CT%3E()%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20_x%3A%20RecursivePartial%3CState%3CT%3E%3E%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20_y%3A%20State%3CRecursivePartial%3CT%3E%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20_x%20%3D%20_y%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20create_2%3CT%3E()%7B%0D%0A%20%2F*%0D%0A%0D%0A%20*%2F%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20x%3A%20RecursivePartial%3CState%3CT%3E%3E%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20y%3A%20State%3CT%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F*%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Type%20'State%3CT%3E'%20is%20not%20assignable%20to%20type%20RecursivePartial%3CState%3CT%3E%3E'.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Types%20of%20property%20'value'%20are%20incompatible.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Type%20'T'%20is%20not%20assignable%20to%20type%20RecursivePartial%3CT%3E%5BP%5D%3E'.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Type%20'T%5Bstring%5D'%20is%20not%20assignable%20to%20type%20'RecursivePartial%3CT%5BP%5D%3E'.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20*%2F%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20x%20%3D%20y%3B%20%0D%0A%7D#src=type%20RecursivePartial%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5BP%20in%20keyof%20T%5D%3F%3A%20RecursivePartial%3CT%5BP%5D%3E%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20State%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%7B%20value%3A%20T%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20create_1%3CT%3E()%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20_x%3A%20RecursivePartial%3CState%3CT%3E%3E%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20_y%3A%20State%3CRecursivePartial%3CT%3E%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20_x%20%3D%20_y%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20create_2%3CT%3E()%7B%0D%0A%20%2F*%0D%0A%0D%0A%20*%2F%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20x%3A%20RecursivePartial%3CState%3CT%3E%3E%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20y%3A%20State%3CT%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F*%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Type%20'State%3CT%3E'%20is%20not%20assignable%20to%20type%20RecursivePartial%3CState%3CT%3E%3E'.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Types%20of%20property%20'value'%20are%20incompatible.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Type%20'T'%20is%20not%20assignable%20to%20type%20RecursivePartial%3CT%3E%5BP%5D%3E'.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Type%20'T%5Bstring%5D'%20is%20not%20assignable%20to%20type%20'RecursivePartial%3CT%5BP%5D%3E'.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20*%2F%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20x%20%3D%20y%3B%20%0D%0A%7D#src=type%20RecursivePartial%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5BP%20in%20keyof%20T%5D%3F%3A%20RecursivePartial%3CT%5BP%5D%3E%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20State%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%7B%20value%3A%20T%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20create_1%3CT%3E()%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20_x%3A%20RecursivePartial%3CState%3CT%3E%3E%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20_y%3A%20State%3CRecursivePartial%3CT%3E%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20_x%20%3D%20_y%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20create_2%3CT%3E()%7B%0D%0A%20%2F*%0D%0A%0D%0A%20*%2F%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20x%3A%20RecursivePartial%3CState%3CT%3E%3E%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20y%3A%20State%3CT%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F*%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Type%20'State%3CT%3E'%20is%20not%20assignable%20to%20type%20RecursivePartial%3CState%3CT%3E%3E'.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Types%20of%20property%20'value'%20are%20incompatible.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Type%20'T'%20is%20not%20assignable%20to%20type%20RecursivePartial%3CT%3E%5BP%5D%3E'.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Type%20'T%5Bstring%5D'%20is%20not%20assignable%20to%20type%20'RecursivePartial%3CT%5BP%5D%3E'.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20*%2F%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20x%20%3D%20y%3B%20%0D%0A%7D#src=type%20RecursivePartial%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5BP%20in%20keyof%20T%5D%3F%3A%20RecursivePartial%3CT%5BP%5D%3E%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20State%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%7B%20value%3A%20T%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20create_1%3CT%3E()%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20_x%3A%20RecursivePartial%3CState%3CT%3E%3E%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20_y%3A%20State%3CRecursivePartial%3CT%3E%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20_x%20%3D%20_y%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20create_2%3CT%3E()%7B%0D%0A%20%2F*%0D%0A%0D%0A%20*%2F%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20x%3A%20RecursivePartial%3CState%3CT%3E%3E%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20y%3A%20State%3CT%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F*%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Type%20'State%3CT%3E'%20is%20not%20assignable%20to%20type%20RecursivePartial%3CState%3CT%3E%3E'.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Types%20of%20property%20'value'%20are%20incompatible.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Type%20'T'%20is%20not%20assignable%20to%20type%20RecursivePartial%3CT%3E%5BP%5D%3E'.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Type%20'T%5Bstring%5D'%20is%20not%20assignable%20to%20type%20'RecursivePartial%3CT%5BP%5D%3E'.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20*%2F%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20x%20%3D%20y%3B%20%0D%0A%7D#src=type%20RecursivePartial%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5BP%20in%20keyof%20T%5D%3F%3A%20RecursivePartial%3CT%5BP%5D%3E%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20State%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%7B%20value%3A%20T%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20create_1%3CT%3E()%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20_x%3A%20RecursivePartial%3CState%3CT%3E%3E%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20_y%3A%20State%3CRecursivePartial%3CT%3E%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20_x%20%3D%20_y%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20create_2%3CT%3E()%7B%0D%0A%20%2F*%0D%0A%0D%0A%20*%2F%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20x%3A%20RecursivePartial%3CState%3CT%3E%3E%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20y%3A%20State%3CT%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F*%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Type%20'State%3CT%3E'%20is%20not%20assignable%20to%20type%20RecursivePartial%3CState%3CT%3E%3E'.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Types%20of%20property%20'value'%20are%20incompatible.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Type%20'T'%20is%20not%20assignable%20to%20type%20RecursivePartial%3CT%3E%5BP%5D%3E'.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Type%20'T%5Bstring%5D'%20is%20not%20assignable%20to%20type%20'RecursivePartial%3CT%5BP%5D%3E'.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20*%2F%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20x%20%3D%20y%3B%20%0D%0A%7D)

Comment: As Information: Based on the docs from the current Version 2.4 Recusive Types are not allowed for Type Alias https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html "However, it’s not possible for a type alias to appear anywhere else on the right side of the declaration..."

Comment: @Magu, I don't think that's relevant here; the recursive type only mentions itself in a property, which is allowed.  (The fact that the type compiles without error is an inidication that it's fine).  The weirdness here has to do with type checking.

Comment: @tugend, I'm not seeing this error on the 2.5.0-dev.20170627 version of typescript that I'm using.  Maybe it's fixed?  Not in a position to track it down at the moment

Comment: The issue remain the same using typescript@rc.

Should I try a different version than the RC and how do I get it? I couldn't find any tags like that on 'https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript'.

Comment: I can recreate the issue for both typescript 2.4 and 2.5@rc. As you yourself, @jcalz, mention on the [github issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17799) it is not fixed on either version.

Comment: Thanks for following up here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like a bug to me.  Workarounds:

As I noticed in [the Github issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17799#issuecomment-323453616), the first and best workaround is probably to turn on the `strictNullChecks` [compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html).  I really recommend turning it on and keeping it on in general, since it is so useful.

---

If you don't want to do that, you can always just use a [type assertion](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/type-assertion.html) to tell the compiler that you know the type better than it does.  If the compiler is really resistant about doing an assertion, you can pass it through an assertion of `any`, like so:

```
function create_2<T>(){
    let x: RecursivePartial<State<T>>;
    let y: State<T>;
    x = y as any as RecursivePartial<State<T>>; // I know it!
}
```

---

If you don't want to do that, you could change the definition of `RecursivePartial<>` to the following:

```
type RecursivePartial<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]?: T[P] | RecursivePartial<T[P]>;
};
```

This is, I believe, effectively the same thing, but the compiler has an easier time seeing that you can always assign a value of type `T` to a variable of type `RecursivePartial<T>`.

---

Hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: We want to wait setting strictNullChecks due to how much of the code base we have to change. All three solutions work though. Thank you! =D. We are most likely going with the last solution for now.

Comment: Had a similar problem and adding ```as any``` to the end proved to be the best solution in my case. Though it has to be pointed out that usually it is not a good solution.